# Why isn't my for loop adding more than one random value to my list?

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop

I'm trying to create a bubble sort algorithm in java and I'm trying to create a list with random integers in it with a for loop, however it only ever has one value. This is the code:

```
public class bubbleSort {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    int length = getLength();

    System.out.println(length);

    List<Integer> randomList = createArray(length);

    System.out.println(randomList);

}

public static int getLength() 
{
    System.out.println("Please enter how long you want the array to be");

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    int length = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

    return length;
}

public static List<Integer> createArray(int length) 
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    List<Integer> randomList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int x = 0 ; x < (length + 1) ; x++);
    {
        int randomnumber = rand.nextInt((100 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        randomList.add(randomnumber);
    }

    return randomList;  
}

}
```

Comment: typo : `for(int x = 0 ; x < (length + 1) ; x++);` - remove the last `;`

Comment: @MoajizHussain - Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add [Java] to the title - this is what the tags (the blue boxes under your question) are for. And if in hindsight you consider your question so trivial that you shouldn't have even written it - you can delete it using the "delete" link under the question.

Comment: Please don't add tags or "closed" to the question title. If one of the answers helped you solve this question, mark it as accepted to indicate that your problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<Integer> createArray(int length) 
{
   Random rand = new Random();

   List<Integer> randomList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

   for(int x = 0 ; x < (length + 1) ; x++)
   {
        int randomnumber = rand.nextInt((100 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        randomList.add(randomnumber);
   }

   return randomList;  
}
```

Your problem is here.

You should only create a single Random instance that you use to generate your random numbers.

This is because the random numbers are from a seed value, and when you don't provide a seed for the random number number generator generator, it will be created with a seed value from epoch time, so all your numbers are the same because of this.

A simple solution would be to update your `createArray(int length)` to take a random instance, like so `createArray(int length, Random random)` and use this instance to generate the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no semicolon (;) after your for loop declaration .That is why the loop keeps exiting after the first loop,
It should be

```
for(int x = 0 ; x < (length + 1) ; x++)
{
    int randomnumber = rand.nextInt((100 - 1) + 1) + 1;
    randomList.add(randomnumber);
}
```

And why do you have a (length +1)..if you want the size of the random list to be the size of the length ,you should remove the +1.